How do I use linked-list-allocator in Rust?
I am just beginning my rust journey.
I am trying to create a linked_list_allocator, but am having problems due to my lack of experience. Can anyone help?
My Cargo.toml looks like this:
[package]
name = "norris-test"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
linked_list_allocator = "0.10.5"

I then have src/main.rs as the sample code from the repo with some edits by me:
use linked_list_allocator::LockedHeap;

#[global_allocator]
static ALLOCATOR: LockedHeap = LockedHeap::empty();

pub fn init_heap() {
    let mut byte1: u8 = 1;                   // Hardcoded as a byte at one
    let mut byte2: u8 = 10;                  // hardcoded as a byte at 10
    let heap_start = byte1;                  // I know this needs to be a mutable byte
    let heap_end = byte2;                    
    let heap_size = heap_end - heap_start;
    unsafe {
        ALLOCATOR.lock().init(heap_start, heap_size.into());  // Converted head_size into a byte using .into()
    }
}

fn main() {
}


When I try to build the program, I get the following error:
david@Device-001-D-L:~/Documents/rust-projects/norris-test$ cargo build
   Compiling norris-test v0.1.0 (/home/david/Documents/rust-projects/norris-test)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:14:31
   |
14 |         ALLOCATOR.lock().init(heap_start, heap_size.into());
   |                          ---- ^^^^^^^^^^ expected `*mut u8`, found `u8`
   |                          |
   |                          arguments to this method are incorrect
   |
   = note: expected raw pointer `*mut u8`
                     found type `u8`
note: method defined here
  --> /home/david/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/linked_list_allocator-0.10.5/src/lib.rs:90:19
   |
90 |     pub unsafe fn init(&mut self, heap_bottom: *mut u8, heap_size: usize) {
   |                   ^^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `norris-test` (bin "norris-test") due to 1 previous error

The emphasis ---- ^^^^^^^^^^ expected *mut u8, found u8`` implies that there is a type mismatch but I am unsure of how to resolve this due to my noviceness.

I don't know what you're trying to achieve, and what I think you're trying to do is very wrong even ignoring the compiler error. Can you give some background on what you're trying to do and why?

I wanted to do some background research on crates used by RedoxOS found here: https://gitlab.redox-os.org/redox-os/kernel/-/blob/master/Cargo.toml?ref_type=heads I saw it used linked_list_allocator found here: https://crates.io/crates/linked_list_allocator and I was intrigued by it. I wanted to learn more about how to use it and play around with it in my code.

The linked list allocator manages a block of memory. You have to allocate that block yourself - for example, a statically allocated u8 array - and then pass in the base address and size of the block. The allocator will allocate smaller chunks out of this bigger block.

Maybe something like let heap = [0u8; 1024], and then pass heap.as_ptr() and heap.len() to allocator's init()...

The core issues is, that the allocator manages a block of memory, as mentioned by @nneonneo. Thus to solve this you need to pass the init method a memory block.
Also please note, that a local variable here is insufficient, because that will get cleaned up after you exit the function. The allocator has to be valid for the entire length of the program, since it is a #[global_allocator].
e.g. This will compile and give the Allocator 1024 bytes of space
use linked_list_allocator::LockedHeap;

const HEAP_SIZE:usize = 1024;
static mut HEAP_ALLOC:[u8;HEAP_SIZE] = [0;HEAP_SIZE];

#[global_allocator]
static ALLOCATOR: LockedHeap = LockedHeap::empty();

pub fn init_heap() {
    unsafe {
        ALLOCATOR.lock().init(HEAP_ALLOC.as_mut_ptr(), HEAP_SIZE.into());  // Converted head_size into a byte using .into()
    }
}

fn main() {
}


When I run this code, I get the following error message: ```memory allocation of 56 bytes failed
Aborted (core dumped)


Well, you don’t actually call the init_heap function, so any allocations will fail, since the allocator is not initialized.

Adding init_heap() to the main function still causes the memory allocation to fail. How do I initialize ALLOCATOR?
